# switching noise from ltc3780

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost

I have currently built a buck-boost converter using LTC3780 on a breadboard following this deisgn.
[image]

[image]

The circuit is calculated and designed to accommodate the input voltage given in the schematic. I have checked countless times and ensure that there is no mistakes in the connections. However the output that I am getting is only a noisy 6V. The switching signals that I observed on the oscilloscope is also fairly noisy. Can someone enlighten me how to troubleshoot this converter?

Thank You

Comment: Breadboard switcher = noise. Show how you implemented the R1||R2 circuit for current limiting. Absolutely any differences between the picture circuit and your reality on breadboard must be disclosed to avoid wasting people's time. THIS IS IMPORTANT.

Comment: [this app note from linear technologies](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an47fa.pdf) talks about high speed design "breadboarding" starting on page 26.  While heat issues are harder to deal with this way, I think it is possible to breadboard high frequency circuits (which is all a switcher is).  It is just a) hard, and b) messy.  With the availability of cheap PCB services out there, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Are you talking about something like this [jumble of breadboards](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UtspqS5CmCo/Tptd5bdvD4I/AAAAAAAAAG0/EfdtqeIpEIY/s1600/Remember4.jpg) At this site? http://readingjimwilliams.blogspot.com/2011_10_01_archive.html

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry abt that. I have updated the actual implementation of the circuit on the breadboard. The 2 resistor on the right are the sense resistors. The green wires running below the IC are the gating signals from the controller

Comment: Thanks for the picture. It is absolutely clear that this is a very inappropriate way to test a 400MHz multi-amp power supply. I added some positivity to my answer.

Comment: 400kHz, sorry. The edges are stil likely in multi-MHz area.

Comment: @AndrewSpott, Where did you get this Appnote dinosaur? It is 25 years old! We should't advise this kind of dead technology here, in the era of 0402/0201-size SMD components.

Comment: @AliChen: Ha!  That is a Jim Williams op note, and he was designing with precise high frequency op amps (>100MHz at least) in that style of breadboard.  I'm pretty sure that is more than sufficient for a 400kHz switcher.  It seems that was his preferred method of testing and working on ideas, from laptop2d's link and [another, more recent app note](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an120f.pdf) from 2011 (see page 25 and on).  Bob Pease also liked to work on circuits with this style of breadboard.

Comment: [Here](http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-100.pdf) is an app note from 09 talking about different ways of breadboarding.

Comment: I don't believe this kind of breadboarding has any value this days. I did this kind 35+ years ago. Wire inductances must be horrible with all radial 1/4W resistors, and capacitances must be quite lower than you can get for a real production PCB. So the results of these hair-wire might be a big disappointment when made with real SMD components on a real PCB. Today for this kind of "proof of concept" I use the ExpressPCB mini-board servce - nice simple development tools and five days turn-around, for ~$100 for 4-layer. I use modern components that simply cannot be hair-wired.

Comment: @AliChen _"I use modern components that simply cannot be hair-wired."_ - Like 144-ball BGAs? [Oh wait...](http://koti.kapsi.fi/jahonen/Electronics/Stuff/BGA_rework.jpg) ;)

Comment: @marcelm, and you expect this hair-wire to work to chip specifications? Good luck... Actually I meant 0402 and 0201 caps and resistors in USB 3.1 Gen2 environment.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to build a prototype of a high-frequency switcher on a breadboard and expect good functionality from this. The functionality and actual ripple levels critically depend on placement of surface-mount components in so-called "high-current" switch loops,  [see this (and many more similar) appnotes](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an136f.pdf), where parasitic inductance of interconnect plays fundamental role.

Prototyping of switchers must be done on a pilot PCB. Even then, when doing a prototype layout, it is highly recommended to strictly follow a layout recommended by manufacturer, including suggested components, because they put significant efforts to make their product (IC) to work to advertised specifications.

ADDITION: The best approximation of recommended layouts can be done on a piece of two-sided copper (non-perforated) board, and use carbide-tipped scoring knife to isolate islands of copper in accord with recommended placement.

ADDITION2: Just found another method of good quality prototyping technique - ["Manhattan Style"](http://www.foxcomputer.se/The%20Handyman's%20Guide%20to%20Manhattan%20Style.pdf). Instead of using a scoring knofe, the method is to cut pads out of a (thinner, 16 mils) one-sided copper-clad substrate in necessary shapes using scissors, and then glue the pads on a bigger copper-clad substrate. This should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your advice. I have decided heed your advice to test the circuit on PCB. The following is my schematic and PCB, I have tried to follow the design consideration given on the datasheet as much as possible. could you guys give me some feedback on my design?

[image]

[image]

Thank You