# Is my PCB good?

Tags: pcb, via, review

I's my first time designing a PCB board and I would like to have your professional inputs and know if I made any major design error.

[image]

The design is available here : https://easyeda.com/editor#id=7DUTAUa1DW

Logical Schematic : https://easyeda.com/editor#id=7DUTAUa1DW

The chip used is a MAX17135 and most of the layout is from the  Typical Operating Circuit of the datasheet (https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX17135.pdf)

What I see that can maybe considered bad is that I had to use a lot of vias to cross the 17 unchanged data lines between the CON1 and the CON2 connector.

Comment: Here is a very related topic, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259558/switching-noise-from-ltc3780/259564#259564

Comment: No help from me: http://imgur.com/a/femzY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid to tell you, but the design is pretty much wrong at almost every point. All high-current switching paths are implemented with skinny traces. Have you chance to read their [application note](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX17135EVKIT.pdf) with recommended layout? My advice is to get their layout as close as possible with all recommended surface-mount components, and make only small modifications to your needs.

ADDITION1: Here is a link to [Application note](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an136f.pdf) from Linear Technology that explains problems with high-current loops in switching power supplies and mitigation technique, with layout examples of what does "wide and short" means, and use of solid ground planes.

Comment: I don't seen anything related to trace width in this notice, where did you see that ? Also, the power line will only have a very low load, (like ~100mA only).

Comment: First item in PCB layout and Grounding, page 22: "Minimize the inner loop area created by the boost
converter high-switching current connections. Place
D1 and C3 close to the IC such that the traces connecting
the LXP pin to the anode of D1, the cathode
of D1 to C3, and C3 to the PGND pin are kept as
short as possible to minimize the loop area contained
within these connections. Make these connections
with ***short, wide traces***."

Comment: Thank you Wesley, appreciated. I don't have this kind of patience...

Comment: No patience was needed, I just clicked the url, "Cmd + F" and typed "trace". This shows the extent of lack of research by the OP.

Comment: Woah, woah, woah, no need to be harsh there. FYI, i've spend countless hours reservhing for this project over the course of several months. I was simply noting that *in the document linked by @AliChen* there was no mention of trace anywere. The problem I have with these instruction is they are really unclear, like "wide trace" :how wide is it ? 1mm ? 10 mm ? 200 m ? I'm sorry if this feel like noob question to you but as I said it's my first PCB, and you've got to stuble before you run...

Comment: @RemyGrandin -- sorry if that felt harsh. The passage I quoted is actually on the document you provided. Anyway, I didn't mean to discourage you, I'm sorry. Wide in Switch mode PSU = all the width you can accommodate. Use pours instead of traces even. Look at pg 10 of the App note.

Comment: Thanks for all the advices, I will try to make a better one now ^^

Answer (score 3):

That board is a non starter mostly for poor placement and lack of solid grounding, causing massive loop areas.

A quick note for newbies with this sort of stuff is that the eval kit documentation probably includes board layouts that will work.

For switching power supplies the schematic is only half the schematic, the layout parasitic RLC (Especially L) form the other half and are just as important.

Back to the drawing board I am afraid, and do not use the autorouter for this sort of stuff (Also, why the mixed technology, go SMT you will be much happier).

Comment: What do you mean by "lack of solid grounding" ? Should I try to use les vias on the ground track ? What problem can cause loop areas ? Can you expand on that ? I didn't go SMT forst becaus i was afraid of not be able to manualy weld such tiny components, and becaus i saw the fact that throught hole component gave me "de facto" vias to help me in the path finding

Comment: Lack of solid grounding == skimpy little traces that snake all over the shop, the vias are less of a problem then the fact you have completely ignored the datasheet layout reccomendations. Current flows in loops (always) and the more physical area those loops have the more inductance they have... Inductance begets voltage drops when you apply a high dI/dt step change in current and this is a bad thing in such circuits. Switched mode supplies are all about the Cin/Switch/Inductor/Catch diode/Cout loops, and most people use polygons for these rather then tracks for a reason.

Comment: I would also comment that most who have been around a bit will be wincing at the choice of a Maxim part for a fairly jellybean function, many of us have been burned by 6 month leadtimes from them at least once. Layout wise, rip it up and start by pouring a copper ground polygon covering the entire back of the board, they try really hard not to break it up, place inductor and any required boost cap first, then Cin/Diode/Cout for the switchers keeping the loops as small as possible, then everything else.... Not ideal but it will get you closer.

Comment: I will try to do all this, thanks for the help. About your remark on maxim, it's not a professional project, only a side project, (and I already have the maxim chips I need, so I should be good on that side ^^), but I will keep it in mind if I ever make another PCB project.